# no se puede ordenar un Query en Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

tengo esta estructura de documentos en Firestore:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este código que trae todos aquellos documentos que tengan un campo *pcIdCuenta* = TRUE;  los muestra en mi lista. pcIdCuenta puede tomar el valor de cualquier id de documento de la coleccion cuentas ("digitaldev", "famrosales", "jrosales", etc.)

```
TabHomeFragmet.fsdbData.collection("cuentas")
            .whereEqualTo(pcIdCuenta, true)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for(DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                            aListaContactos.add(
                                new ContactoModel(
                                    doc.getId(),
                                    doc.get("nom").toString().trim(),
                                    doc.get("img").toString().trim(),
                                    aListaContactos.size()
                                )
                            );
                            adaContactos.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se pudo obtener la lista de contactos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

pero cuando pongo esta línea

```
.orderBy("nom", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

después de .here y antes de .get(), ya no devuelve la consulta y no trae nada.

Comment: ¿Aparte de Aristen Valley hay otros nombres en ese apartado?